# Cannot find out what's causing Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

It seems like the version of actionpack should be fine as it meets every requirement below.

The command I'm using is `bundle update rails rspec-rails gon sprockets-rails carrierwave kaminari` but I've also tried bundle update rails.

```
cpc upgrade % bundle update rails rspec-rails gon sprockets-rails carrierwave kaminari
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies.......
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    actionpack

    rails (~> 5.0.7) was resolved to 5.0.7, which depends on
      actionpack (= 5.0.7)

    rspec-rails (~> 3.0) was resolved to 3.8.2, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.0)

    sprockets-rails (~> 3.2.1) was resolved to 3.2.1, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 4.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In Gemfile:
    carrierwave (~> 1.2.2) was resolved to 1.2.3, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 4.0.0)

    email_validator was resolved to 1.4.0, which depends on
      activemodel

    rails (~> 5.0.7) was resolved to 5.0.7, which depends on
      activemodel (= 5.0.7)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    activerecord

    apartment was resolved to 0.24.3, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 3.1.2)

    composite_primary_keys (~> 9.0.7) was resolved to 9.0.10, which depends on
      activerecord (~> 5.0.0, >= 5.0.7)

    ledermann-rails-settings was resolved to 2.2.0, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 3.1)

    rails (~> 5.0.7) was resolved to 5.0.7, which depends on
      activerecord (= 5.0.7)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    carrierwave (~> 1.2.2) was resolved to 1.2.3, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 4.0.0)

    kaminari was resolved to 1.1.1, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)

    rails (~> 5.0.7) was resolved to 5.0.7, which depends on
      activesupport (= 5.0.7)

    shoulda-callback-matchers (= 1.1.1) was resolved to 1.1.1, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 3)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "carrierwave":
  In Gemfile:
    carrierwave (~> 1.2.2)

    carrierwave_direct was resolved to 0.0.15, which depends on
      carrierwave

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 5.0.7)

    carmen-rails was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
      rails

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    bootstrap-slider-rails (~> 5.3.3) was resolved to 5.3.7, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.0)

    factory_girl_rails was resolved to 4.3.0, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.0.0)

    font-awesome-rails (>= 4.2.0.0) was resolved to 4.6.1.0, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.1)

    jquery-rails was resolved to 3.0.4, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)

    js-routes (~> 1.4.4) was resolved to 1.4.4, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.2)

    quiet_assets was resolved to 1.0.2, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.1, < 5.0)

    rails (~> 5.0.7) was resolved to 5.0.7, which depends on
      railties (= 5.0.7)

    roadie-rails (~> 1.3.0) was resolved to 1.3.0, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.3)

    sass-rails (~> 5.0.6) was resolved to 5.0.6, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rake":
  In Gemfile:
    rake (~> 10.3.2)

    annotate was resolved to 2.5.0, which depends on
      rake

    rails (~> 5.0.7) was resolved to 5.0.7, which depends on
      railties (= 5.0.7) was resolved to 5.0.7, which depends on
        rake (>= 0.8.7)
cpc upgrade %
```

Comment: Try deleting your `Gemfile.lock` and then run `$ bundle install`.

Comment: @MarkMerritt - Won't that automatically upgrade some gems that I don't want to yet?

Comment: As long as you specify versions in your Gemfile for the gems you do not want to upgrade then it won't...but also keep in mind that the gems you are not upgrading may also be an issue

Comment: For the code above, why do the versions seem to be fine?

Comment: @MarkMerritt - I removed the gemfile.lock but got the same error as above.